# Expression String Builder window always opens when I start QGIS

Tags: qgis

When I open QGIS, the Expression String Builder window always opens and I have to cancel it in order for my project to open. How can I stop this behavior?

Comment: can you indicate QGIS version ?

Comment: Have you tried to (copy it before to save it) delete your QGIS profile directory ?

Comment: I deleted the profile directory and it still happened. I'm on version 3.4-10

Answer (score 1):

I right clicked on the main map layer and selected Toggle Editing, then saved the Project and the issue went away.